# Retrieve interpolated transform from tf2_ros::Buffer

Tags: interpolation, ros, tf2-ros

Can anyone confirm that the following returns the **interpolated** transformation from the tf2_ros_buffer_ at the query_stamp?

```
auto t = tf2_ros_buffer_.lookupTransform(frame_a, frame_b, query_stamp);
```

And more specifically, is this Cartesian interpolation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and not exactly, the way that `lookupTransform` works (as part of [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2)) is that it performs spherical linear interpolation (SLERP) between the transform right before and the transform right after the query time (see the original [TF paper](http://wiki.ros.org/Papers/TePRA2013_Foote?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=TePRA2013_Foote.pdf)).  This is a trick taken from the computer graphics world that facilitates a constant angular speed model.

The equation for slerp is below where `q_a` and `q_b` are the quaternions representing the frames, `q` is the output quaternion, `t` is the ratio of times, and `theta` is half of the shortest path angle between `q_a` and `q_b`

[image]

Generally the results are used in Cartesian form though.

You can checkout the source code [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/6c5ac09d8a2f046e16100d49543c3e345b1dd20d/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp) (look `lookupTransform`, `transformTF2ToMsg`, and the core TF2 interpolation code [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/589caf083cae9d8fae7effdb910454b4681b9ec1/tf2/include/tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h)).

Comment: You're one of the reasons for which Stack Overflow is surely the coolest place on the internet

Comment: can we therefore agree that this is basically doing: i) linear interpolation on translation, ii) slerp interpolation on rotation?

Comment: @Employee Yes! That is exactly what is happening.  And I appreciate your kind words ^_^